# angular cli AOT compile error

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli

I am using the simple starter angular cli example that is on the angular cli site. I created a service OUTSIDE the app folder and included it in the app module in the providers ..etc. Dont ask me why..Just imagine its a service i create that I plan to share between different angular projects. Now ng serve works but ng serve --aot breaks build. Here's the error I receive. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks

**Here is a link to my project structure**

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/20493/94971/eVkgsEDXM8Kfzs1/upload.png

**ng serve -- aot error below:**

ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider rep
lacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol Injectable in C:/ANGULAR PROJECTS/testNgCLI/node_modul
es/@angular/core/src/di/metadata.d.ts, resolving symbol OpaqueToken in C:/ANGULAR PROJECTS/testNgCLI/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_t
oken.d.ts, resolving symbol OpaqueToken in C:/ANGULAR PROJECTS/testNgCLI/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_token.d.ts

**CLI version:**
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.24
node: 7.3.0
os: win32 x64

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the code that is inside the service. This happened to me too, and the error was the same:

> Calling function **'makeDecorator'**, **function calls are not supported**. Consider rep lacing the function or lambda with a reference to an **exported function**

You are using some anonymous function called `makeDecorator`. For the code to be ready for AoT, you need to move that to separate function and export it (also it needs to be classic `function`, not `=>` lamda).

You need to have something like this:

```
export function makeDecorator() {
    // implementation...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

All your code should be inside a single `app` folder to follow [Angular 2 StyleGuide](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#app-structure-and-angular-modules). Also, I saw your issue in the AngularCLI. The CLI follows the Style Guide strictly so the issue will probably be closed.

Inside the `app` folder you could create something like this:

```
app/
|
+-- shared/
    |
    +-- utils/
        |
        + -- file.service.ts
    +-- shared.module.ts // this will be the module that declares and exports shared files
+-- app1/
    |
    +-- app1.module.ts // declare and export app1 stuff
+-- app2/
    |
    +-- app2.module.ts // declare and export app2 stuff
+-- app.module.ts // import app1, app2, and shared
```

I would suggest you don't name things `app1` or `app2` cause it's just bad practice, something more explanatory like `admin` or `user`, for example, will be easier to navigate when having to fix a bug.

Hopefully that's clear enough. If not I can try to explain better.

Comment: Tx for replyng . I named them as such(app1,2.) to make my point clear to you with out much explntn of what I wanted. I dont think the above structure that you suggested would work for the case where I want to keep a single copy of my global module that I want to share bw diff projs.Proj's here are similar to the root app' folder(s) in your pic above  which will have their own ang cli.json files. Canyou tell me why the cli throws the error in AOT?or is there any other way I could achieve what I want.My reqmt isnot to create morethan 1 copy of global Mod on my machine that I can share betwn apps